# Counting word "pairs" in excel between different columns

Tags: excel, function

I'm wondering if it's possible to do this in excel:

Let's say I have these columns:

```
Column A | Column B  
Apple | Red
Apple | Green
Pear | Green
Pear | Green
```

Is it possible for me to count how many times a set of "pairs" appears. 
For example -

I want to count how many times "pear" and "green" appeared in my spreadsheet next to each other (not individually).

So for the above I should get:
    Apples + Red appears 1 time
    Apples + Green appears 1 time
    Pear + Green appears 2 times

I tried using the COUNTIF function, but I don't think it can count a set of pairs like this...

If the above is possible... is it further possible to break down the data by time? For example, we have these columns:

```
Column A | Column B | Column C
3/7/2013 | Apple | Red
3/7/2013 | Apple | Red
3/8/2013 | Apple | Red 
3/8/2013 | Pear | Green
3/8/2013 | Pear | Green
3/9/2013 | Apple | Red  
3/9/2013 | Pear Green
```

If I want to organize the data by day, how can I do this? For example:

I want to display that on 3/7/2013, Apple + Red appeared 2 times, but on 3/8/2013, Pear + Green appeared 2 times and Apple + Red only appeared once.

Is it also possible to organize data by weeks or months this way? (During the month of January, I got 20 Apple + Red "pairs"

Let me know if anything was unclear in what I was asking

Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a pivot table. Then you can group data however you wish and add counts.

Comment: I know how to make a pivot table and I can add the column information... but how do I add the "counts"?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column to your data, which concatenates your data (ideally with delimiters to avoid value clashes) e.g. In Col D1 put formula

> =A1&"|"&B1&"|"&C1

Give it a heading of Vals, and then create your pivot table from all the data

As an example I created this sample data which has 2 employees, Fred & Bill and a number of rows for each on 2 days. For 3-Jul, both Fred and Bill appear 3 times, but on 4-Jul Fred appears once and Bill 5 times.

[image]

My pivot table shows this result (which is hopefully what you're after)

[image]

**EDIT :**

For your situation, you probably need two extra columns, one called `'Pair Name'` which concatenates B & C, and another called 'Pairs' which concatenates A, B & C.

Then in your pivot table you can drag 'Pair Name' into the Column Labels, and 'Pairs' into the Sum of Values.